# Is there any density function such that the center of mass of a semicircle about its diameter is half its radius?

Tags: calculus, functions

I am currently taking a Calculus II class in college. We recently went over how to find the center of mass of a lamina with uniform density. The professor worked through the example of a semicircle to show that the center of mass lies along the line of symmetry and at a radius of $\frac{4R}{3\pi}$ from the center. This is slightly below the midpoint of the radius, $\frac{1}{2}R$. I considered whether increasing the density as you moved further from the center could bring the center of mass to $\frac{1}{2}R$, although this was not discussed in class.

Consider the semicircle bounded by $f(x) = \sqrt{R^2-x^2}$ and the x-axis. **Does there exist any function $\rho(y)$ such that $y_{CM}=\frac{1}{2}R$ ?**

The generalized center of mass $y_{CM}$ can be written:

$$\frac{\int_0^R 2y\rho(y)\sqrt{R^2-y^2}\ dy}
       {\int_0^R 2\rho(y) \sqrt{R^2-y^2}\ dy} = \frac{1}{2}R$$

My intuitive first attempt was to try a linear direct proportion density $\rho(y) = ky$ cand so solve for $k$. However, this fails because:

$$\frac{2\int_0^R y(ky)\sqrt{R^2-y^2}\ dy}
       {2\int_0^R  (ky)\sqrt{R^2-y^2}\ dy} = 
  \frac{\int_0^R ky^2\sqrt{R^2-y^2}\ dy}
       {\int_0^R ky  \sqrt{R^2-y^2}\ dy}   = \frac{3\pi}{16}
$$

So the center of mass of such a lamina is always the same no matter the value of $k$. After the calculation it seems so obvious: increasing $k$ increases the moment about the axis, but it also increases the mass; there is no net effect. My next idea was to rewrite the equation for the center of mass by multiplying the bottom integral out of the denominator:

$$ 2\int_0^R y\rho(y)\sqrt{R^2-y^2}\ dy = R\int_0^R \rho(y) \sqrt{R^2-y^2}\ dy $$

and differentiate the integrals to get the integrands, but of course they are definite integrals, so their derivatives are zero. But if we ignore the bounds, I have a feeling that it is not quite right to get the integrands from the integrals as such because of the multiple variables:

$$  2y\rho(y)\sqrt{R^2-y^2} = R\rho(y)\sqrt{R^2-y^2} + \frac{dR}{dy}\int\rho(y)\sqrt{R^2-y^2}$$

and since $R$ is a constant, $\frac{dR}{dy} = 0$:

$$ 2y\rho(y)\sqrt{R^2-y^2} = R\rho(y)\sqrt{R^2-y^2} $$

$$ \rho(y) (2y-R)\sqrt{R^2-y^2} = 0 $$

$$ \rho (y) = 0\ ??$$

and I am getting nowhere to finding $\rho(y)$ outright. I think that this problem is beyond my abilities as a second-semester calculus student with no experience in multivariable calculus. Does this problem have a solution at all, and is it possible for me to understand with my basic calculus knowledge?

Thank you.

Comment: Since $\frac{4}{3\pi}$ is less than 1/2 and $\frac{3\pi}{16}$ is greater than 1/2, it seems like some function should exist.

Comment: What about $\rho(y) = y^\alpha$?

Comment: @Théophile, I am not sure what you mean by $\alpha$. Could you explain?

Comment: Apoapsis - As long as the point you want the center of gravity to be at is within the interior of the region begin integrated (more generally, within its convex hull), then there will always be a density map that will result in that center of gravity. If you allow singular densities, then you could even have the center of mass on the boundary.

Comment: I suspect that you want $\rho$ to be continuous, otherwise a piecewise function that uniformly distributes half of the mass over the region $y<\frac R2$ and the other half over $y>\frac R2$ does the trick. You might update your question with this requirement.

Comment: @Apoapsis I meant for some constant $\alpha > 0$. Note that when $\alpha = 0$, we effectively have $\rho(y) = 1$, i.e., a constant density, and the centre of mass is too low. And when $\alpha = 1$, we have $\rho(y) = y$, and the centre of mass is too high. So for some $0 < \alpha < 1$, the function $y^\alpha$ should be just right. (See @ Michael Lugo's answer.)

Answer (score 1):

If $\rho(y) = y^0 = 1$, then the center of mass is at $4R/(3\pi)$.  If $\rho(y) = y^1 = y$, then the center of mass is at $(3\pi)R/16$.  Now, let the function $g$ be defined by setting $g(\alpha)$ to the location of the center of mass when $\rho(y) = y^\alpha$.  Then $g$ is continuous (proving this is a little messy but should be intuitively obvious), and $g(0) = 4R/(3\pi), g(1) = (3\pi)R/16$, so by the intermediate value theorem there exists some $\alpha \in [0, 1]$ with $g(\alpha) = R/2$.  However this doesn't tell you what $\alpha$ is.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s one function that works, derived from inspection of the integral for center of mass.

We’re basically looking for some $f(y)$ such that $\frac1M\int_0^Rf(y)dy=\frac R2$. A simple choice is $f(y)=\frac M2$. Comparing this to the integral for the center of mass, we have $$
y\rho(y)\cdot2\sqrt{R^2-y^2}=\frac M2,
$$ so $$
\rho(y)=\frac M{4y\sqrt{R^2-y^2}}.
$$ This has the unfortunate property of being undefined at $y=0$ and $y=R$, but its value there doesn’t affect the integral, anyway. One can think of this mass distribution as being created by squeezing a $2R\times R$ rectangle of uniform density straight in from the sides into a semicircle.

Clearly, for any other solution of the integral equation above, $\rho(y)=\frac{f(y)}{2y\sqrt{R^2-y^2}}$ will also place the center of mass at $y=R/2$. All of these mass distributions have the property that the density is uniform along the lines $y=\text{const}$. Removing this constraint opens the door to even more density functions that will work. For example, any function that’s symmetric about the $y$-axis will keep the center of mass at $x=0$.